# Rails loop to add data in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm using [the Facebook Messenger gem](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger) in order to send messages to recipients on Messenger. What is the best way to loop over my database entries and add a piece of data to the deliver hash?

Here is a piece of code to explain what I want to achieve, I want to add through an each loop x elements in the elements:[]:

```
Bot.deliver({
      recipient: {
        id: sender
      },
      message: {
        "attachment":{
          "type": "template",
          "payload":{
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements":[
            {
              "title": title,
              "image_url": image_url,
              "subtitle": subtitle,
              "default_action": {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": cta_url
              },
              "buttons": [
              {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": cta_url,
              "title": cta_text
              },
              {
                "type": "element_share"
              }
            ]
            }
                        #ADD HERE*
          ]
          }
        }
      }
    }, access_token: access_token)

-----------------------------------------

    #LOOP to add several items like this one:
            {
              "title": title1,
              "image_url": image_url1,
              "subtitle": subtitle1,
              "default_action": {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": cta_url1.html_safe
              },
              "buttons": [
              {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": cta_url1,
              "title": cta_text1
              },
              {
                "type": "element_share"
              }
            ]
            }
```

I tried to find a simple solution but since I'm learning rails, I don't know what's the best way to add some data to the hash to create a new request.

Comment: Copy the sample source code to this question.

Comment: Make this question stand alone. You didn't even mention the gem name. Do not rely on links to explain your question.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: `hash.map do |h| ...`. You should at least attempt to solve this.

Comment: Have a look at  `deep_merge` it may help you